# Jquery multiselect plugin - how to get the selcetd text

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am implementing this JQuery UI multiselect from http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget

Here is the code

```
var array_of_checked_values = $("select").multiselect("getChecked").map(function(){
return this.value;    
}).get();

$("#ctl00_MainContent_lblAssigned").html(array_of_checked_values.join('<br/> '));
```

Here i am getting the value.I want the selected Text.How to do that? Can anyone help me?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You want to return the innerHTML, instead of the value

```
var array_of_checked_values = $("select").multiselect("getChecked").map(function(){
return this.innerHTML;    
}).get();
```

Comment: No..i want selected text...for example value is 23 text is Mohan.I want Mohan.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get the text:

```
return $('.ui-multiselect-checkboxes').find('[aria-selected="true"]')
                                      .next('span').text();  // to get the text
```

---

See your multiselect changes the dom structure so you have to find the element which has this attribute `[aria-selected="true"]` which is the selected checkbox and next to this elem is the span which holds the text of it, so you have to return the text of it.

Comment: But while i m selecting single checkbox its not returning the text..while i am selecting 3 checkboxes its returning 3 times text continuously..